# Change Round css in IONIC 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a button with shape round as follows:

```
<ion-button expand="full" class="shadow-red" shape="round">Signup with</ion-button>
```

The class shadow-red is:

```
.shadow-red{
    box-shadow: 0px 14px 25px rgba(182, 30, 30, 0.59);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

So I tried many different ways to change the round shape but since it isn't a css class doing the following didn't work.

```
.round{
  border-radius:5px!important;
}
```

I tried adding `border-radius:5px!important;` to `ion-button` class, `button`, `.btn`, and many other combinations but none of them worked.

I have also tried to add to variables.css the following lines and none of them worked:

```
--ion-button-round-border-radius: 5px;
--ion-button-border-radius: 5px;
--ion-border-radius: 5px;
--border-radius: 5px;
....
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use the shape attribute, now you can change the look of the button to your wishes. One thing to change is the expand attribute. If you set it to *full*, you remove the left and right borders (see in docs). And so you can't set or change the border-radius. Set it to *block* and you will still have a full-width button.

```
<ion-button expand="block" class="shadow-red">Signup with</ion-button>
```

Use the following CSS custom properties as described in the [Ionic 4 docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties).

```
.shadow-red{
    --border-radius: 5px;
    --box-shadow: 0px 14px 25px rgba(182, 30, 30, 0.59);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Simply changing `full` to `block`, fixed my issue. TYVM!

Comment: border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
not working this type

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me. As per your need change the height and width value to meet your requirement.

```
<ion-button slot="end" shape = "round" style="height: 3rem; width : 3rem">
    <ion-icon name="create-outline" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting here for future references.

If you want to change the ionic button radius we can use following css. it is working on `expand="block"` attribute

```
ion-button {
  --border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

But in ionic button, when we use `expand="full"` attribute it does not work. so to overcome this limitation we can use CSS `Pseudo-elements`.

*to add a border radius to the bellow button*

```
<ion-button fill="solid" type="submit" color="primary" expand="full" >Login</ion-button>
```

as bellow image we need to select the native element within the shadow DOM

[image]

***we can use below Pseudo-elements selector***

```
 ion-button::part(native) {
    --border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

above will add the radius on the ionic button with `expand="full"` attribute